# Cmake not exporting code because Xcode 1.5 is not supported

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake, clion, juce

Due to hardware limitations, I am trying to create a plugin using the JUCE framework in CLion. But Cmake isn't working, I keep getting this error every time I try to generate build files.

I've tried both methods of command line and the Cmake application and both have the same error.

[Error message in the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piSK4.png)

```
CMake Error:
      Xcode 1.5 not supported.

CMake Error: Error SetGlobalGenerator called with null
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  Language 'C' is currently being enabled.  Recursive call not allowed.

CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

[Error message in the command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZCLV.png)

```
CMake Error:
  Xcode 1.5 not supported.

CMake Error: Could not create named generator Xcode
```

I don't have Xcode installed on my computer, and I can't install it even if I wanted to.

Comment: What build chain tools do you have? Xcode is shipped with that and without build chain tools you can't do anything and cmake may be confused by this.

Comment: Yeah, I think I just have the default build chain tools that CLion comes with, I was searching for a way to download Xcode's toolchain but I couldn't find any way how.

Comment: Assuming that cmake is able to find compiler, try different generator `Ninja` should be ok. So: `cmake -G Ninja .. <your other configuration arguments>`

Comment: Ok, I tried that but now I got this: 

`CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/zaccharyedwards/PluginDev/test2/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".`

I did install Ninja, but if I try to open it it says there's an error loading build.ninja: No such file or directory.